# How can I extract only the lines that have a specific string AND THEN sort the numbers at the end the extracted lines , from lower to higher value

Tags: grep, sort

The below 3 example lines are extracted by :

```
grep  "Time to convert event = "[1-9] output.log
```

However I need to then be able to SORT from lower to higher, the number after `Time to convert event = x.xxxxxx`

How can this be done ?

```
2019-10-31 07:18:17.770 INFO [WORKER_Thread-4] [blahblah:212] [userID:] [eventID:] [objectID:] [] Time to convert event = 5.516262
2019-10-31 07:18:17.770 INFO [WORKER_Thread-4] [blahblah:212] [userID:] [eventID:] [objectID:] [] Time to convert event = 19.516262
2019-10-31 07:18:17.770 INFO [WORKER_Thread-4] [blahblah:212] [userID:] [eventID:] [objectID:] [] Time to convert event = 0.316262
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` allows to a) specify a field separator (`-t`), b) sort by a field `-k` and c) sort `-n`umerically.

```
grep "Time to convert event = [1-9]" output.log | sort -n -t= -k2
```

Where we exploit that there is only one `=` and that right before the number, you need.

Comment: Fiximan,  Thanks for your feedback, it seems to work somewhat,

Comment: I get: 11.6, 10.5, 1.03, etc, so not in order..  I am limited in my comment length.

Comment: @OliversDad could you copy the exact command you tried?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, it better be. Edited.

Comment: some number are in order some are not:

Comment: grep "Time to convert event = "[1-9] output.log | sort -n -t= -k2

Comment: See if moving `[0-9]` into the double quotes fixes it.

Comment: I now use :  grep "Time to convert event = [1-9]" output.log | sort -n -t= -k2  , everything from 1.0 or greater is sorted, but I no longer see anything like 0.0xxxxx, or 0.xxxxxx.  So numbers < 1.0 are not extracted and sorted.

Comment: Use `[0-9]` instead?

Comment: Guillermo, Fiximan,  That is it, I can't believe I did not check that.  This works :  grep "Time to convert event = [0-9]" output.log | sort -n -t= -k2 .  Thank You.